# Showing Custom Options on Magento Product Page

Tags: magento

I am having a problem displaying custom options on the product page in Magento. I'm using Modern as the base for my theme, and changing themes doesn't seem to have any effect. The catalog.xml is almost the stock one for the theme.

When viewing the page, I get the message "Please specify the product's required option(s)." but nothing shows up. Additional information that have been added to the attributes show, but no product specific custom options.

Looking with developer hints, I see that /catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml is not appearing on the file. Could something be missing in one of the layout .xml files?

Any idea what might be going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried enabling the default template and it still doesn't work, try creating a new product with some options and see if that works. If that still doesn't work, enable the logs and pop them open and see if there are any errors being recorded during rendering. Also, make sure that they aren't just being hidden using CSS or JavaScript (try turning off the latter, for the former use Firebug to inspect the page)

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is going on. Completely replacing base, default and modern (the theme is based on modern) has no effect. I have another early copy of the site on a different server and it's working fine. I exported the database of the current non-working site and imported it into the earlier and and now the custom options no longer work there which makes me suspect that something in the database options is amiss. But what could be set wrong in options?

Comment: When I come across weird crap like this, I often suspect some config value has been changed at a lower scope. Of course, I am assuming you've done the usual cache flush/index build/etc. Maybe also check local.xml for some covert <remove name="custom.options"> (or whatever the handle is).

Comment: I gave you the bounty as it ultimately helped lead me to the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your layout files to the default Magento layout files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already did, and they are more-or-less identical. I'll double-check, but I've only added a couple things to the layout, I haven't removed anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was related to this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/forums/forum/1228365/topic/4978977

The difference is that the attribute was set to container2 in my case when I need it set to container1.

Hope this helps someone else with this issue.